# Probability - Markov's inequality (Tossing Coin)

Tags: probability

Regarding the following question:

> For a biased coin with probability **p** it lands on H, show that if
> we toss the coin 20 times, the probability that the sequence "HH"
> appears **less** that twice is bounded by
> $\frac{19\left(1-p^{2}\right)}{18}$ (for e.g, the sequence "HH"
> appears twice in the sequence "HHH").

---

---

**EDIT:** I think I got it. We need to use Markov's with t=18 and then we get:

$\mathbb{E}\left[X\right]=\mathbb{E}\left[\stackrel[i=1]{19}{\sum}x_{i}\right]=19\left(0\cdot p^{2}+1\cdot\left(1-p^{2}\right)\right)$

---

---

I'm pretty sure that we need to use Markov's inequality:

> For random variable $X:\Omega\to[0,\infty)$, we get:
> $P\left(X\geqslant t\right)\leqslant\frac{\mathbb{E}\left[X\right]}{t}$ with $t>0$

and bound the probability with it.
I know that the probability of getting HH in two coin tossings is $p^{2}$, hence the probability for **not** getting HH in two coin tossings is $\left(1-p^{2}\right)$, and that is the probability we have in the bound.

Based on that, I think that we need to define an indicator random variable with $\left(1-p^{2}\right)$ as its probability, but I'm having difficulties to do that because I'm not sure how to refer to two tossings of the coin. Can we say that out of 20 tossings of the coin we have 19 possible adjacent sequences of HH?
So we can define: $X$=Number of adjacent sequences that are not **HH**? Such that $X_{i}=1$ if the sequence **is** HH and 0 otherwise.

so for $t=\frac{18}{19}$ we would get from Markov's:

$P\left(X\geqslant\frac{18}{19}\right)\leqslant\frac{\mathbb{E}\left[X\right]}{\frac{18}{19}}=\frac{19\cdot\mathbb{E}\left[X\right]}{18}=\frac{19\cdot\sum\left(\mathbb{E}\left[X_{i}\right]\right)}{18}=\frac{19\cdot\left(1-p^{2}\right)}{18}$

I'm pretty sure I'm missing something and/or mistaken